# How to make clicking a link in external app use running firefox profile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-14.04, firefox-profile

I use more than one firefox profile on Linux.  If I click on a link in an external application, instead of opening the URL in a running browser window, I get a firefox profile manager dialog.

How can I make these applications open the URL in an already-running firefox?

Ideally I'd like to be able to nominate a process or profile as the one to open links I click on, but it doesn't do what I expect even if there is only one profile running (it seems it only works if that profile happens to be the "default" profile).

For example:

```
Ensure no firefox processes are running
Start firefox with firefox -P
Create a new profile
Check "Use the selected profile without asking at startup"
Click "Start Firefox"
Start emacs
M-x org-mode (in non-emacs speak, that's Alt-x followed by typing org-mode, followed by return key)
Type http://google.com/
Click on the resulting link
```

What I expect: new tab opens in the running firefox, viewing google.com

What I get: profile manager dialog opens again

Comment: To use an existing instance, you need to have remoting enabled. Drop the `-no-remote` argument on the target instance.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I felt sure you had the answer, but surprisingly I can still reproduce the problem after dropping --no-remote (which I got into the habit of using and evidently forgot did anything more than --new-instance).  I've edited the steps to make it easier to reproduce what I'm seeing, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a file ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop containing the following line:

```
Exec=firefox -P -no-remote %u
```

That was useful to start firefox from the desktop launcher.  However, that's used to control how other applications launch firefox also.  Changing the line to this fixed the problem:

```
Exec=firefox %u
```

To continue autostarting firefox with different commandline options, I created a separate ~/.config/autostart/firefox-autostart.desktop file.